# add formset to form with django

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a model Choice which contains a foreignkey to Poll model:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 0

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return myForm
```

in myForm i try to forcing the visualization of two Choice field without the click on "Add another Choice" as is usually done with other Field:

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):       
    ExampleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Choice, extra=2)
    formset = ExampleModelFormSet(queryset=Choice.objects.none())

class Meta:
    model = Poll
```

But when reload the page no Choice are showed. Can anyone help me?!

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Remember the `InlineModelAdmin` class adds: `extra` and `max_num` where you can control this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra